# Uploading files Dropbox

Tags: windows, dropbox, synchronization, uploading

I made a mistake 1 mounth ago and I sent a 2Gb folder to my Dropbox. My internet speed is very low and I can't wait until finishing uploading so everytime I start Windows, I have to close Dropbox before it starts uploading! is there any solution to stop sync ?

Comment: In the Dropbox settings, choose "selective sync", and uncheck the 2GB folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open options and apply selective Sync to disable the folder you don't want to upload

or you can remove it from the dropbox directory into another folder on your computer ( as in cut )

Comment: I did the first solution but the same problem
http://imgup.com/data/images/20502.png
and when I tried to delete the folder from Dropbox directory, I didn't find it

Comment: Have you tried moving it from the dropbox directory and into another folder?

Comment: Yes I did, Well, Problem resolved, I removed all folders from dropbox and I disabled all from selective Sync ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Just cut it from your dropbox folder and past somewhere else on your PC.

Double check by accessing dropbox website and check your account there. Delete already uploaded part if it exist(to avoid downloading it again).